# Bootstrap Datepicker : Changing start date to tomorrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using the `Bootstrap` `datepicker` and the following is my `jQuery` code:

```
$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
    /* endDate: '+0d', */
    startDate: '+1d',
    weekStart: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    startView: 2,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
});
```

The following is what I get:

[image]

I want have the start date highlighting on tomorrow according to our requirement.  I have found one option `defaultViewDate` on the `Bootstrap` `datepicker` documentation.  (http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html)

It states that I have to set the `year`, `month`, and `day` key of `defaultViewDate`. But I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 1):

Try following;

```
$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
    defaultViewDate: { year: 1977, month: 04, day: 25 }
});
```

It should be in the format of Object with year, month and day keys. For more information please see here;

https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Your format for the `startDate` option looks correct, but I do see some other errors in your JavaScript that may be confusing the `DatePicker` (and causing your `startDate` to be ignored):

1. The `autoclose` option should be formatted as a `Boolean` and should be either `true` or `false`.
2. The `minView` option that you have defined should actually be: `minViewMode`.
3. The `forceParse` option should be formatted as a `Boolean` and should be either `true` or `false`.
4. You have a trailing comma that follows your final option (`forceParse`), which should be removed so that there is no comma after the final option.

If you correct the problems listed above, I believe you will begin to see a correct `startDate`.