# defaultViewDate not working on Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

OK so I have seen [Bootstrap Datepicker : Changing start date to tomorrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322680/bootstrap-datepicker-changing-start-date-to-tomorrow) which I thought would get me right but it doesn't.

```js
$("#datepickerStart, #datepickerEnd").datepicker({
  todayHighlight: true,
  endDate: '+367d'
})

var fullDate = new Date();
  console.log(fullDate);
var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth() + "";
if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1)
  twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;
var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + "";
if (twoDigitDate.length == 1)
  twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
var $currentDate = twoDigitMonth + "/" + twoDigitDate + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();
var $endYear = fullDate.getFullYear() + 1;
  console.log($currentDate);
  console.log($endYear);
var $endDate = twoDigitMonth + "/" + twoDigitDate + "/" + $endYear;
  console.log($currentDate);
  console.log($endDate);

$("#datepickerStart").find("input").attr("value", $currentDate);

$("#datepickerEnd").find("input").attr("value", $endDate);

$("#datepickerEnd").datepicker({
  defaultViewDate: {
    year: $endYear,
    month: twoDigitMonth,
    day: twoDigitDate
  },
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
})
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-3 colFlushL hideme" id="endDateWrapper">
  <label class="control-label" for="datepickerEnd">End <small><span class="text-muted">(max 1 year)</span></small>
  </label>

  <div class="input-group date colFlush" data-provide="datepicker" id="datepickerEnd">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datepickerEnd" value="">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not beautiful but it works - apart from default view for the end picker (the value works fine) (ie the values in the input fields are fine and the 367 day limit work.

I wonder if it is because the `id` and the `data-provide` are attached to the `input-group` not `input` but you have to do that to make the icon work as part of the datepicker and NOT having the icon work is daft from a UX point of view.

Any thoughts?

PS We are talking about http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#id3

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seem to come from your hack of the input yes...

This work [and the icon too](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#component) :

```js
$("#datepickerStart, #datepickerEnd").datepicker({
  todayHighlight: true,
  endDate: '+367d'
})

var fullDate = new Date();
  console.log(fullDate);
var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth() + "";
if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1)
  twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;
var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + "";
if (twoDigitDate.length == 1)
  twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
var currentDate = twoDigitMonth + "/" + twoDigitDate + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();
var endYear = fullDate.getFullYear() + 1;
  console.log(endYear+' '+twoDigitMonth+' '+twoDigitDate);
var endDate = twoDigitMonth + "/" + twoDigitDate + "/" + endYear;

$("#datepickerEnd").attr("value", endDate);

$("#datepickerEnd").datepicker({
  defaultViewDate: {
    year: endYear,
    month: twoDigitMonth,
    day: twoDigitDate
  },
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
})
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-xs-5 colFlushL hideme" id="endDateWrapper">
  <label class="control-label" for="datepickerEnd">End <small><span class="text-muted">(max 1 year)</span></small>
  </label>

  <div class="input-group date colFlush" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input  id="datepickerEnd" type="text" class="form-control" name="datepickerEnd" value="">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a gazillion for that. The hack is me trying to follow Bootstrap 3. BS 2 used `<i>` tags but BS 3 wants us to use `<span>` for addons (see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic) and this causes lots of problems. I shall now abandon the documentation as this keeps coming up and the `<i>` tag seems to work just fine. Thanks

Comment: @OldMauiMan edit : take a look, it work with `span` too XD

Comment: Really - I am just too tired to care. I will go through my code tidying up the datepickers (I have 10 of the buggers). Thanks again but I was happier when I could blame Bootstrap :-) Life eh! (ps every time I do @Blag at the beginning it eats it - sorry)

Comment: Sadly I cannot get this all to work. I sort one thing and the next breaks. In this version the one year limit is not working but the today highlight IS!!!! (Edit oops noi it isn't) So I will just deleted the default date so the end date just shows today and users can sort it out (just trying to help the user but now will be confusing them). Did you change anything else apart from moving the id from the `div` to the `input`? I have spent about half an hour on this again and it simply is not a priority but it is just so frustrating. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: My bad, you can't use a double instantiation `.datepicker({...})` on same DOM, so yes, it'll not work! you have to use [setter method](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html) after the first instantiation if you want to change some setting. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Sorry bit lost - where is the double instantiation (is that the  `$("#datepickerEnd").datepicker({`)? PS Thanks for you efforts on this BTW

Comment: This worked great when passing a Date object did not work for me thank you, the addition of one is not needed for the ```getFullYear()``` though